# Why does my python not show in cmd despite me adding the path to my system variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I recently started to using PyCharm Community so i'm pretty new to this. I added the anaconda3 and python path to my variables. "conda" works in my cmd but python just opens a windows store page where i can download python. I checked the path with "where python" and added these. Does anyone have suggestions, because I wanted to use pyinstaller.

Comment: "I added the anaconda3 and python path to my variables" Are you sure it worked? When you do `echo %PATH%` at the command line, do you see a path to a valid Python? When you manually try using that path, followed by `\python.exe`, does it launch the Python installation you expect it to?

Comment: "but python just opens a windows store page where i can download python." This is because the PATH also includes a path to the wrapper program that loads up the store page. Do you understand how PATH is used, in particular, in what order the paths are checked?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the paths were echoed. User\xx\anaconda3\python actually works and shows me the version. I gotta be honest the whole PATH is still a little new to me. So if i type in python without anaconda3\ in front of it should it work or do i always have to add it before.

Comment: "I gotta be honest the whole PATH is still a little new to me." Then you have a computer-usage question, not a programming question. You should try to find tutorials, and also look around on https://superuser.com.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Okay, thanks a lot. Just followed a course for python and some things are not as well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Type `py` instead of `python` in your command prompt.
The default command for running python commandline interface has changed.